# How Stack Overflow has implemented caching?

Tags: performance, caching, cdn, google-cdn

Not sure if Stack Overflow uses caching to enhance the loading speed of its pages, but if it has, it has done a great job. There are many components to be updated. I this picture you see every single second there are many components to be updated. How Stack Overflow does it so perfectly?[image]

Comment: From occasional hiccups when browsing the StackExchange sites, I can say that StackExchange uses [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) for "accelerating" (caching) portions (all?) of the site for better experierence.

Comment: Is this a [meta] question?

Answer (score 5):

This is answered much more comprehensively on Meta.SE in this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69172/186281). The highlights, however, are:

- Basically everything is cached, especially everything served to anonymous users.
- [They use Redis servers with 96 GB of Ram](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/). This server keeps an "L1 Cache" of recently set and read values. These values are compressed before sending them to Redis. They also use IIS's [Output Caching](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-performance-settings/walkthrough-iis-output-caching)
- Each site has 3 types of caches:

  - "Local" (user sessions, view counts, etc)
  - "Site" (hot question ids, user acceptance rates)
  - "Global" (user inboxes, API quotas)

There are even more details on [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html) , though this is nearly 5 years old at this point. There is a [newer article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html) (from 2014) that mentions that there are two additional levels of caching involved as well:

- SQL Server (the entire database sits in memory). As of 2013, the [database servers had 384 GB of memory](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/)
- SSD (hit only when the SQL server cache is warming up...as not something I'd consider "cache", but it's mentioned in the article).